# OpenCart: Search no longer works after repositioning

Tags: javascript, forms, opencart2.x

I am designing my own template by making changes to the default template code of OpenCart 2.0.2.0. After repositioning the Search field, it no longer works: it will not submit on pressing Enter, and the search value is not submitted in the URL when clicking the search button in the form (the form submits though).

In order to try and find what goes wrong when relocating the input field, I have made a fresh installation of OpenCart on my WampSever, and without changing anything else, I moved the input field to the main nav, right after the categories UL -- by simply copying the PHP tag that prints the search template:

```
<?php echo $search; ?>
```

Nothing else. The form submits on pressing Enter on the keyboard, and it submits on clicking the search button, but the search parameter is no longer appended to the URL, e.g.

```
http://localhost/opencart/index.php?route=product/search&search=macbook
```

I need your help to find out why this happens and how I can move the search field without losing its functionality. I suppose this is Javascript related but not sure how.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question:
Yes, it is Javascript related. Since the search input field is not wrapped in a , in order to submit it, and get the search query, two jQuery functions have been written (in catalog/view/javascript/common.js, lines 64-81).
These functions get the search input value by first referencing the  within which the input is originally located:

[line 68]

```
var value = $('header input[name=\'search\']').val();
```

[line 79]

```
$('header input[name=\'search\']').parent().find('button').trigger('click');
```

To make it work, I had to replace the two instances of "header" with the ID of the menu:

```
var value = $('#menu input[name=\'search\']').val();
```

Sorted then!
Hope this helps some other OpenCart beginner like myself :)